# Combination of TCP communication and Rest API for mobile application

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tcpserver, tcpsocket

I have a mobile application published on google play and its currently working quite well with around 6k-8k simultaneous users. Actually I need some help here to redesign my architecture and communication flow between server and android client. Here is the scenario.

1- 1-linux server on private network. Not accessible from internet.

2- 1-Windows server on public network.

3- 1-Mobile application.

Communication goes like this.

Every Request from mobile lands on windows applications server over Rest API developed in asp.net using C#. The rest API then communicates with the linux server Over TCP protocol. Fetches the data from linux server and sends it back to the application over rest API. This works well for small number of users for around 8k. The main problem is the communication between windows application server and linx server due to TCP restriction.

Communication between rest API is linux server is

Rest API creates a TCP socket using server IP and PORT for every new request and then

```
      1-Logins to system using username and password
      2-Sends the command to get specific data. 
      3-Receives the desired data. 
      4-Logouts from linux server. 
      5-Disposes off the socket and sends this result to mobile application.
```

Due to large amount of request from mobile user the above steps a repeated again and again, which eventually chocks the port on the server. After discussion with the server owner I have to create a long TCP session with the linux server which will remain connect for the whole time and all request will be send over this channel without disconnecting/disposing the socket every time and recreating. I want a way to crate a long TCP session with linux server. But this is not possible with Rest API. My Point is how can I achieve this in current scenario. I have plat form restriction of C# and dotnet. I don`t have much knowledge of dotnet as I an android developer. Any help will be greatly appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a WebSocket for your persistent connection? In JavaScript, the code looks something like this sketch:

```
var theSocket = null;
function interactServer() {
    theSocket = new WebSocket(document.URL.replace("http", "ws"));
    theSocket.onopen = function() {theSocket.onopen = null; notifyServer(<initialization request>);};
    theSocket.onmessage = function(event) {<function to handle a message>(event.data);};
    theSocket.onclose = function() {<cleanup code>};
    }
```

where notifyServer is a function that sends a REST request to the server. Make interactServer the onload function for your initial HTML screen so that the connection gets instantiated first thing.

The problem with using XHR is that the server platform may leak socket resources even when the browser closes a socket. A Windows-based platform certainly will. A WebSocket connection is persistent across requests and therefore doesn't create a resource-leakage problem.